# Zombie telnet process pile up while using spawn with Expect

Tags: linux, process, tcl, expect, telnet

I intend to make a `telnet` connection with a network device using `Expect`, and it involves sending commands to the device multiple times and also rebooting the device as well. I thereby need to make the `telnet` connection again and again.

```
proc dputs {msg} {
    if {[info exists ::debug] && $::debug} {
        puts $msg
    }
}

proc open_telnet_session {} {
    set sResult FAIL 
    set prompt "(\r|\n|\r\n).*?(#|%|>|\\\$) $"
    #set prompt "#|%|>|\\\$ $"
    set timeout 60
    if {$::tcl_platform(platform) eq "windows"} {
        spawn {c:\Dinesh\telnet_32bit.exe} $::device_ip
    } else {
        spawn telnet $::device_ip
    }
    set ::device_ip $spawn_id
    expect {
        timeout {puts "Timeout happened while spawning telnet session";return $sResult}
        eof     {puts "EOF happened while spawning telnet session";return $sResult}
        "login: $" {send "$::device_uname\r";exp_continue}
        "password: $" {send "$::device_pwd\r";exp_continue}
        -re $prompt 
    }
    set sResult PASS 
    return $sResult
}


proc send_cmd_to_device {cmd} {
    set timeout 180
    dputs "cmd : $cmd"
    set sResult FAIL 
    set prompt "(\r|\n|\r\n).*?(#|%|>|\\\$) $"
    set ::spawn_id $::device_ip

    if {[catch {send "$cmd\r"} errorMsg]} {
        puts "Failed to send the commands..."
        puts "Reason : $errorMsg"
        return $sResult 
    }
    expect {
        timeout {puts "Timeout happened while sending commands to telnet session";return 0}
        eof     {puts "EOF happened while sending commands to telnet session";return 1}
        "invalid token" {puts "Invalid token error from device";exp_continue}
        "$cmd" { dputs "\n\n matching the cmd\n\n";set ::actual_cmd_match 1;exp_continue}
        -re $prompt {
            if {$::actual_cmd_match} {
                dputs "\n\n final prompt match \n\n"
                set ::actual_cmd_match 0
                set sResult PASS 
            } else {
                dputs "\n\n still waiting for prompt match \n\n"
                exp_continue
            }
        }
    }
    return $sResult
}
proc close_telnet_session {} {
    set sResult FAIL 
    set ::spawn_id $::device_ip
    #This will send 'Ctrl+]' to close the telnet connection gracefully
    if {[catch {send "\x1d"} errorMsg]} {
        puts "Failed to send the commands..."
        puts "Reason : $errorMsg"
        return $sResult 
    }
    expect { 
        timeout {return $sResult}
        eof {return $sResult}
        -nocase "telnet>"
    }
    if {[catch {send "quit\r"}]} {
        puts "Failed to send the commands..."
        puts "Reason : $errorMsg"
        return $sResult 
    }
    expect {
        timeout {return $sResult}
        eof {set sResult PASS}
    }
    return $sResult
}
```

Even though I am closing the connection gracefully, I can still see the process running in the task manager (in Windows 7). (Same case with Linux as well, telnet process shows up as `<defunct>` process).

If I run the script overnight and say I have to open the `telnet` connection about thousands of time (as my script involves rebooting the device multiple times and thus the management connection will be lost), it will end up reducing the performance.

This will lead to memory leak or failure in resource allocation when this happens continuously.

After searching a lot, I end up with `exp_close` and `exp_wait`.

```
# Killing the process in Windows...
exec taskkill /pid $telnet_process_id
exp_close -i $::device_id 
exp_wait -i $::device_id; # This becomes a blocking call..
```

With the above code, `exp_wait` is keep on waiting and it is getting blocked in there.

To avoid the same, I have used `-nowait` flag as well, but still no use. It is returning immediately and the process still stays in the process chart.

What should be the optimal way to handle this issue?

Comment: You'd use `exp_close` after you see `eof`. You probably want to see why you're getting timeouts in your `close_telnet_session` proc.

Comment: @glennjackman : With `exp_close`, I end up with `spawn_id: spawn id exp4 not open` error message, since the `Expect` is already observed `eof` from the telnet process. Btw, I have added `timeout` handler in `close_telnet_session` just for the fail-safe case. It is not that I am receiving `timeout`, but a precaution.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, spawned process connections are usually terminated with a call to [close](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/exploring-expect/9781565920903/ch04s08.html).  Is expect on windows different than expect on *nix in that regard?

Comment: `close` also not working and this behaviour is common for windows and Linux systems.